# python: how to override str.join?

Tags: python, string, subclass

We have a subclass of str (call it MyStr), and I need to be able to control how str.join interacts with my subclass.

At minimum, a join of all MyStr's should produce another MyStr, and joining of MyStr and "plain" str should throw a TypeError.

Currently, this is what happens: (MyStr subclasses unicode)

```
>>> m = MyStr(':')

>>> m.join( [MyStr('A'), MyStr('B')] )
u'A:B'

>>> ':'.join( [MyStr('A'), 'B', u'C'] )
u'A:B:C'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couldn't your class just override `join`:

```
class MyStr(unicode):
    def join(self, strs):
        # your code here
```

This will at least cover the case of `MyStr(...).join(...)`

After @bukzor's comment, I looked up how this works, and it looks like join is a C function that always returns a `unicode` object when called using a `unicode` seperator.

[The code can be seen here](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/unicodeobject.c). Take a look at the `PyUnicode_Join` function, especially this line:

```
res = _PyUnicode_New(res_alloc);
```

So, the result of `PyUnicode_Join` will always be an instance of `PyUnicode`.

The only error case I can see is if the input isn't unicode:

```
/* Convert item to Unicode. */
if (! PyUnicode_Check(item) && ! PyString_Check(item)) {
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                 "sequence item %zd: expected string or Unicode,"
                 " %.80s found",
                 i, Py_TYPE(item)->tp_name);
    goto onError;
}
```

So I don't think it's possible to make this case fail (at least, not while your object extends from `unicode`):

```
':'.join( [MyStr('A'), 'B', u'C'] )
```

Comment: @Brendan Long, Raymond Hettinger: That doesn't work. See: http://pastebin.com/3kuTXG1T

Comment: @bukzor - You're right, overloading `__add__` isn't enough to make `":".join([MyStr("a"), "a"])` fail. Maybe `join` uses format strings? Or it could just be a C function. I took that piece out since the other part (overload `join`) does work.

Comment: Looking at the unicode.join implementation (Objects/unicodeobject.c:PyUnicode_Join) it looks like it just casts everything to unicode unconditionally. Similarly, the str.join implemenation calls unicode.join if any of the items are unicode (or a subclass). @Raymond Hettinger: Do I have this right?

Comment: @Brendan Long: It makes me sad, but it seems true. Now I need to convert this object to not subclass unicode, which presents a myriad of different issues.

Answer (score 0):

`join()` is a `str` method.  If you want to end up with a `MyStr` object afterwards, you to use a `MyStr` ojbect to do the join.

If you want a `TypeError` you'll have to not inherit from `str` and provide all of `str`'s methods yourself (at least the ones that you need).  It's quite possible, though, that this will make them largely useless for normal string operations.